# what is wrong with c++ program.i am beginner please

Tags: c++

i am trying to execute but compiler is giving error.i am not getting any error in this program.this program is based on function overloading.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myfunc(int i);
int myfunc(int i, int j=1);

int main()
{
    cout << myfunc(4, 5) << " "; 
    cout << myfunc(10); 
    return 0;
}

int myfunc(int i)
{
    return i;
}

int myfunc(int i, int j)
{
    return i*j;
}
```

Comment: Which `myfunc()` should be called for `myfunc(10)`?

Comment: You need to share the error you are getting.

Comment: You need to provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, in the first call tomyfunc( )two arguments are specified;
 therefore, no
ambiguity is introduced,
 andmyfunc(int i, int j)is called. 
However, the second
call tomyfunc( )results in ambiguity,
 because the compiler does not know whether
to call the version ofmyfunc( )that takes one argument, 
or to apply the default to
the version that takes two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
int myfunc(int i);
int myfunc(int i, int j=1);
```

you have an ambiguous call once you call

```
foo(42);
```

Which one should be called ?

remove the `=1` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First and most obvious point is your definition for below functions *should precede* their usage:-

```
int myfunc(int i);
int myfunc(int i, int j=1);
```

Second and more subtle point is that you have provided unnecessary overload:-

```
myfunc(2) //ambigous call
```

It would be much better if you use default parameters rather than overloading in your case. So, you provide only one version:-

```
int myfunc(int i, int j=1);
```

This can be called either for one argument OR for two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

How can the compiler tell the difference between these?

```
int myfunc(int i);
int myfunc(int i, int j=1);
```

Remove the default in the latter

PS: Improve the indentation

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to confuse compiler. So only it is throwing error.

```
cout << myfunc(10);

This will execute which function? Its ambiguous.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function overload signatures are ambiguous

```
int myfunc(int i);
int myfunc(int i, int j=1);
               // ^^^^^^^
```

Thus the compiler can't distinguish, which one to use. Change the declarations to remove the default parameter value

```
int myfunc(int i);
int myfunc(int i, int j);
               // ^^^^^
```